# Creating tables tables with a function?

Tags: php, sql

So I put together this functions to create everything I need to run my stuff, and it doesn't work. Doesn't throw an error, just doesn't work. Each query was tested, and they all work, but when combined they don't. Here's the entire code I'm trying to run

```
<?php 
$dbloc = "localhost";
$dbname = "databasename";
$dbuser = "databaseuser";
$dbpass = "databasepass";
$create = mysql_connect($dbloc, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$create);


function buildDB() {
    $sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS company (
        ID          INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        PRIMARY KEY(ID),
        CompanyName        VARCHAR(256),
        HomePage           VARCHAR(1024),
        AboutUs            VARCHAR(2048))"; 
    $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
       ID          INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
       PRIMARY KEY(ID),
       User                VARCHAR(128),
       Pass                VARCHAR(128),
       Type                VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'Visitor',
       Signed              DATETIME)";



MySQL_QUERY;

    return mysql_query($sql1) && mysql_query($sql2);
}
?>
```

What's wrong with it? When I put `private` before the function it was throwing an error, so I removed it. No errors, but doesn't do anything.

Comment: You aren't calling that function anywhere, are you? And global functions don't get visibility modifiers like `private`; that's valid only in classes.

Comment: That's the entire code, I thought that was definition and call of a function. Do I need to call it somewhere, and if so how would I do that?

Comment: Figured, made a call after `}` and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't contain a function call, just the function definition. By adding `buildDB();` after `}` the code executes.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the function.

you could write this in your code:

```
buildDB();
```

under the follow line:

```
mysql_select_db($dbname,$create);
```